# How to use the username auth in python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am recently using the python-social-auth and I've set up correctly to login with facebook and twitter.

Looking at the documentation I read that they support a non-social backend called Username Backend (http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/username.html).

I don't know if it is possible for this package to have some basic forms to get any user to login using the default django auth model or I have to build it by myself. In the link before they wrote that some password handling that I have to add to the pipeline, but I am not very familiar with the pipeline model.

Thanks.